# deleting a column in hansl

Tags: matlab, matrix, gretl

I have a very simple question. I want to delete a column from a matrix in a loop.

In Matlab I use the following:

for a certain i,

X(:,i)=[]

which deletes the column an reshapes the matrix.

I want to know the equivalent in Hansl (Gretl) program, please.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that Hansl the guy who hangs around with Chewbcc?

Comment: i wish :(  do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I know Matlab but no Gretl. I hope you have good luck with that; it doesn't seem to be a very popular tag?

Comment: I know, it doesn't seem to be a popular program. but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it's probably too late for you now, but I just saw your question and maybe it's useful for others.
In hansl (gretl's scripting and matrix language) I could think of several possibilities:

First, if you happen to know the number of columns and the value of i, the solution could use a hard-wired index vector (for i==2 and cols(X)==5 here):

```
X = X[, {1, 3,4,5}]
```

Secondly, since the first solution is probably too restrictive, you could concatenate the left and right parts of the matrix, as in:

```
X = X[, 1: i-1] ~ X[, i+1 :cols(X)]
```

But the problem here is that i must not index the first or last column, or the indexing will produce an error.

So my final suggestion that should work universally is:

```
X = selifc( X, ones(1, i-1) ~ 0 ~ ones(1, cols(X) - i) )
```

The selifc() function discards the column for which the second vector argument has a 0 entry. This also works for i==1 or i==cols(X).
A shorter variation of this final solution might be:

```
X = selifc(X, seq(1, cols(X)) .!= i)
```

which does an element-wise not-equal-to-i comparison (.!=) of the column  indices constructed with the seq() function. But it's probably not as readable as the previous way.

good luck!

Comment: P.S.: by coincidence of timing, a couple of days ago gretl got this new syntax feature for dropping rows or columns. Now you just have to write `X=X[, -i]`, using minus the column number as your pseudo index.